# Merging API JSON response with XML using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, api

I have a tricky question here and I'm looking for some pointers to help me get the result I need.

So, I'm consuming an API for a hotel booking engine, the API is alright, but it is missing a few things which the client has provided in a separate static XML file (like descriptions of rooms, facilities etc).

So, I have 4 things I need to do when a user searches for availability.

1. Get a list from the API of all the room types available. JSON below:

   {
   "results": [
       {
           "id": 147,
           "name": "XXXXXXX Loft XL",
           "description": "XXXXXXX Loft XL",
           "code": "B1K",
           "max_occupancy": 2,
           "level": 2
       },
       {
           "id": 145,
           "name": "XXXXXXX Loft",
           "description": "XXXXXXX Loft",
           "code": "C1K",
           "max_occupancy": 2,
           "level": 1
       }
   ],
   "total_count": 2
   }
2. Get the availability for each room and show the 4 different prices per room inside the room types.
3. Merge the local static XML file which contains the room descriptions, icons, facilities etc with the room type API response.

This is the XML to array:

```
        $roomdata = simplexml_load_file('room-data.xml');

        // put this into an array of sorts
        $roomjson = json_encode($roomdata);
        $roominformation = json_decode($roomjson,TRUE);
```

4. Stitch all the content together and display it on screen for the user to select the room and rate they want.

I've tried putting things into arrays and matching keys (id in this case), but I'm not having much joy, it just keeps them separate.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Here are some code snippets of what I am doing so far to consume the API and try and combine it with the XML.

```
$url = 'https://www.myapi.com'; // this gets the room types

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
    ); 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode the response
    $responseData = json_decode($result, TRUE);

    // Put everyting to the screen with var_dump;
    //var_dump($responseData);

    // With print_r ( useful for arrays );
    //print_r($responseData);

    // List just review ratings with foreach;
    $results = $responseData['results'];

    // create an class for rooms
    $room_types = new stdClass;

    $index = 1;

    foreach ($results as $rooms) {
    // This appends a new element to $room_types, in this case the value is another array
    $room_types_array[] = array('id' => $rooms['id'] ,'name' => $rooms['name'],'description' => $rooms['description']);
    $room_types = (object) $room_types_array;
    }

    // merge the arrays
    $room_data_merged = array_merge_recursive($room_types_array, $roominformation);
```

This is the array response when I try and combine the XML and API for room types:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 147
            [name] => XXXXXXX Loft XL
            [description] => XXXXXXX Loft XL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 145
            [name] => XXXXXXX Loft
            [description] => XXXXXXX Loft
        )
    [room] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 145
                    [roomname] => XXXXXXX Loft
                    [intro] => The 24m² XXXXXXX Loft sets new standards in the intelligent use of space. As a living/working hybrid, it can be easily adjusted to become cozy, business-like or something in between.
                    [introicons] => Array
                        (
                            [iconitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => one-to-two-people
                                            [icondescription] => 1–2 Adults
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [icondescription] => Wi-Fi
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [icondescription] => Kitchen
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [icondescription] => 1 King Size Bed
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [information] => Array
                        (
                            [informationitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [title] => King-Size Bed
                                            [description] => Our lovely beds guarantee the sweetest of dreams thanks to the layered mattress, fluffy duvet and 100% organic bed linen.
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [title] => Fully Equipped Kitchen
                                            [description] => The kitchen comes with built-in Siemens luxury equipment and is capable of pumping out the perfect cappuccinos in the morning and the tastiest of pastas at night.
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => table
                                            [title] => Large Kitchen Table
                                            [description] => At XXXXXXX, a big kitchen table serves as focal point. Use it to work across time zones, host dinner parties or gently rest your head after making deadline.
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => shower
                                            [title] => Spacious Shower Area
                                            [description] => The shower area features an awesome high-pressure shower and amenities.
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [title] => Wi-Fi
                                            [description] => Free, fast and reliable internet (wired & wireless) - EVERYWHERE.
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => coffee
                                            [title] => Living Room
                                            [description] => Lounge-styled living area with Muuto design couch and side table, along with a 32-Inch smart LED TV including BYOC (Bring Your Own Content) option. Complete with prickly-but-cosy green cacti and swappable art.
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 147
                    [roomname] => XXXXXXX Loft XL
                    [intro] => The extra spacious XXXXXXX Loft of 32m² sets new standards in the intelligent use of space. As a living/working hybrid, it can be easily adjusted to become cozy, business-like or something in between.
                    [introicons] => Array
                        (
                            [iconitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => one-to-two-people
                                            [icondescription] => 1–2 Adults
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [icondescription] => Wi-Fi
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [icondescription] => Kitchen
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [icondescription] => 1 King Size Bed
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [information] => Array
                        (
                            [informationitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [title] => King-Size Bed
                                            [description] => Our lovely beds guarantee the sweetest of dreams thanks to the layered mattress, fluffy duvet and 100% organic bed linen.
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [title] => Fully Equipped Kitchen
                                            [description] => The kitchen comes with built-in Siemens luxury equipment and is capable of pumping out the perfect cappuccinos in the morning and the tastiest of pastas at night.
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => table
                                            [title] => Large Kitchen Table
                                            [description] => At XXXXXXX, a big kitchen table serves as focal point. Use it to work across time zones, host dinner parties or gently rest your head after making deadline.
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => shower
                                            [title] => Spacious Shower Area
                                            [description] => The shower area features an awesome high-pressure shower and amenities.
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [title] => Wi-Fi
                                            [description] => Free, fast and reliable internet (wired & wireless) - EVERYWHERE.
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => coffee
                                            [title] => Living Room
                                            [description] => Lounge-styled living area with Muuto design couch and side table, along with a 32-Inch smart LED TV including BYOC (Bring Your Own Content) option. Complete with prickly-but-cosy green cacti and swappable art.
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 146
                    [roomname] => XXXXXXX Loft – Wall View
                    [intro] => A budget smart twist on our 24m² XXXXXXX Loft: All the same smart features, minus a view.
                    [introicons] => Array
                        (
                            [iconitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => obstructed-view
                                            [icondescription] => Obstructed View
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => one-to-two-people
                                            [icondescription] => 1–2 Adults
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [icondescription] => Wi-Fi
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [icondescription] => Kitchen
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [icondescription] => 1 King Size Bed
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [information] => Array
                        (
                            [informationitem] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => bed
                                            [title] => King-Size Bed
                                            [description] => Our lovely beds guarantee the sweetest of dreams thanks to the layered mattress, fluffy duvet and 100% organic bed linen.
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => whisk
                                            [title] => Fully Equipped Kitchen
                                            [description] => The kitchen comes with built-in Siemens luxury equipment and is capable of pumping out the perfect cappuccinos in the morning and the tastiest of pastas at night.
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => table
                                            [title] => Large Kitchen Table
                                            [description] => At XXXXXXX, a big kitchen table serves as focal point. Use it to work across time zones, host dinner parties or gently rest your head after making deadline.
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => shower
                                            [title] => Spacious Shower Area
                                            [description] => The shower area features an awesome high-pressure shower and amenities.
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => wi-fi
                                            [title] => Wi-Fi
                                            [description] => Free, fast and reliable internet (wired & wireless) - EVERYWHERE.
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [icon] => coffee
                                            [title] => Living Room
                                            [description] => Lounge-styled living area with Muuto design couch and side table, along with a 32-Inch smart LED TV including BYOC (Bring Your Own Content) option. Complete with prickly-but-cosy green cacti and swappable art.
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Once I've then got all the room data together, I've got to somehow loop the available rates inside each DIV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You just need to search your various arrays based on some unique key (I guess `id` from your example code.

```
foreach ($results as $rooms) {
    // First index using your unique key
    $result[$rooms['id']]['room'] = $rooms
    // Build a couple of search functions to grab an array based on unique key
    $result[$rooms['id']]['room_info']=search_your_json($json,$rooms['id']);
    $result[$rooms['id']]['room_data']=search_other_data_function($rooms['id']);
}
```

Then you will get an array like:

```
 [
    145=>[
          'room'=>[//array of room],
          'room_info'=>[//array of room info],
          'room_data'=>[//array of room data]
          ],
    147=>[
          //same array structure here
          ]
 ]
```

I think I have your various data sources mis-labled but you should get the idea.

Example search function

```
 search_your_json($json,$room_id){
     $data = json_decode($json,true);//true for an array     
     foreach($data as $d){
      if($d['id']===$room_id){//if it has the right id return the array $d
       return $d
       }
      }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Cool, i'll have a play with that. What should I be replacing search_your_room_info_function with?

Comment: Depends on the structure of your source XML/json or whatever but essentially you need to build a function to loop through, find the common unique Id and return array of the values that relate

Comment: OK, i'll have a go. It's so confusing with these 3 different types of data all trying to mash together into one!

Comment: Your final step should be to cast to a php array or just buildd

Comment: If you show sample json I could hazard a guess what might work

Comment: I'll add it to the question, two secs

Comment: Updated with JSON now, excuse the formatting, the editor wouldn't format it properly.

Comment: I get this error on line 196

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /vagrant/web/web/bookingStep2.php on line 196

Which is this:

$result[$rooms['id']]['room'] = $rooms;

Comment: We should move this to a chat